# intent.putExtra with Parcelable comes out NULL for every extra but without Parcelable everything is fine

Tags: android, object, null, notifications, parcelable

So the porblem is that I am trying to make a notification for my app and can not find why do I get null all the time!
Here is what I do:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("object", object);
        intent.putExtra("year", year);
        Toast.makeText(context, object.getName() + " setUpNotification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And I am recieving a Toast "objectName(whatever it is) setUpNotification"

But when I want to recieve that intent, here is what happens:

```
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent!=null){
                myObject object = intent.getParcelableExtra("object");
                int year = intent.getIntExtra("year", 0);
                if(object !=null){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "in onReceive object != null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(year!=0){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "in onReceive object == null but year is: " + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "in onReceive object task==null and year==0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am recieving that sequence of Toasts:

1. objectName(whatever it is) setUpNotification
2. in onReceive both object==null and year==0

But if I delete only this line of code "intent.putExtra("object", object);" than I will recieve that sequence of Toasts:

1. objectName(whatever it is) setUpNotification
2. in onReceive object==null but year is: 2023

WHY is that? I have no idea!
P.S. I had never had any problems with Parcelable before that, between any activity or enywhere else everything worked perfectly. The problems with Parcelable appears ONLY here.

I have read:
[Parcelable object that receives passed data coming up null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157268/parcelable-object-that-receives-passed-data-coming-up-null)
[Passing parcelable object to new activity returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568546/passing-parcelable-object-to-new-activity-returns-null)
[Why is the parcelable object null in receiving activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496903/why-is-the-parcelable-object-null-in-receiving-activity)
[Android Parcelable -- RetailerOrderActivity.java return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400564/android-parcelable-retailerorderactivity-java-return-null) **and a lot more!**

But that didn't help.